# Parallel execution of the functions and waiting for their completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback, deferred

How can I wait until the end of the two functions, and only after calling callbacks for them to continue the script.

I paid attention to jQuery deferred.then(), but I do not understand how to use it in my case

```
GoogleDriveModule.checkAuth(function(authResult) {
  if (authResult) {
    return parts_count += 1;
  }
});

DropboxModule.isAuthenticated(function(authResult) {
  if (authResult) {
     return parts_count += 1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two deferred objects and resolve them within the callbacks. Then you can wait on both deferreds with [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
var googleDone = $.Deferred(),
    dropboxDone = $.Deferred();

GoogleDriveModule.checkAuth(function(authResult) {
  googleDone.resolve();
  if (authResult) {
    return parts_count += 1;
  }
});

DropboxModule.isAuthenticated(function(authResult) {
  dropboxDone.resolve();
  if (authResult) {
     return parts_count += 1;
  }
});

$.when(googleDone, dropboxDone).then(function() {
    alert("Both authentication checks completed.");
});
```

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: I don't think the difference will be measurable but in absolute terms it will certainly be "slower". The main attraction here is that you can continue chaining or integrate any of the deferreds (the master or either child) into any other async pipeline trivially.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 boolean and check in a callback function if they are ready :

```
var gDriveREADY = false, dBoxREADY = false;
GoogleDriveModule.checkAuth(function(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {
        return parts_count += 1;
    }
    gDriveREADY = true;
    doSomething()
});

DropboxModule.isAuthenticated(function(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {
        return parts_count += 1;
    }
    dBoxREADY = true;
    doSomething();
});

function doSomething(){
    if(dBoxREADY && gDriveREADY){
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callbacks you could toggle a simple flag which the other function checks:

```
var driveDone = 0
  , dropDone = 0
  ;
GoogleDriveModule.checkAuth(function(authResult) {
  driveDone = 1;
  if (authResult) {
    parts_count += 1;
  }
  if(dropDone){
   bothDone();
  }
});

DropboxModule.isAuthenticated(function(authResult) {
  dropDone = 1;
  if (authResult) {
     parts_count += 1;
  }
  if(driveDone){
   bothDone();
  }
});
function bothDone(){}
```

This has less overhead than the deferred method, but is not quite as clean.